# Qual è il significato di "spunti coatti"?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> A questa specie di paralizzante tedio contribuivano in qualche misura le piccole e monotone manie del mio ospite, che mi
>   avevano divertito sul principio, e ora mi inuggivano più di quanto si può immaginare. Queste erano numerose e di varia natura;
>   ne citerò due a titolo di saggio, due **spunti coatti**. A tavola, dove,
>   stante la frugalità dei nostri pasti, c'era spazio d'avanzo, egli provava continuamente il bisogno di farsene davanti uno maggiore;
>   ogni momento spingeva piatti verso di me, allontanava anche gli
>   oggetti meno ingombranti, la saliera, un tozzo di pane, dal proprio campo, e allora soltanto, puntando i gomiti sulla tavola, pareva trovar pace. Inoltre, una volta lavatesi le mani per il pasto,
>   non poteva toccare alcunché di sudicio o supposto tale; se, ad
>   esempio, doveva accostare la seggiola, la sollevava col pugno
>   chiuso per la spalliera, o la spingeva soltanto col mignolo. E altrettali minute stranezze, che io giudicavo ultime e corrotte tracce
>   di proprie qualità della sua stirpe; come, nella fattispecie, di
>   un'antica volontà di dominio e di una raffinatezza divenuta morbosa.

Ho cercato il termine "coatto" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può significare "imposto per forza". Non sono sicura però di aver capito il senso di questo aggettivo nel contesto del brano sopra citato. Significa che l'io narrante si sentiva in qualche modo obbligato a dare questi due spunti al lettore?

Comment: Coatto indica anche nel gergo romanesco un individuo rozzo, arrogante, dalla parlata volgare che vive nelle zone periferiche, suburbane, nelle borgate. Sarebbe interessante vedere come prosegue il racconto per vedere se è questo il significato.

Comment: @abarisone: Ho riportato un brano più ampio, ma non credo che questo sia il significato.

Comment: Sì, in effetti sembra più un comportamento psichiatrico

Answer (score 1):

Guardando la definizione della [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/coatto/) credo che si debba guardare all'accezione 3:

> In psichiatria, di pensiero o impulso che insorgono nella coscienza
>   con carattere di coazione.

La definizione psichiatrica di "coazione" [presa dallo stesso sito](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/coazione/) è:

> In psichiatria, fenomeno morboso caratterizzato dall’insorgenza di un pensiero o di un impulso ad agire, da cui il soggetto non riesce o fatica a liberarsi, pur giudicandoli futili o inconsistenti".

Secondo me quindi gli spunti sono da considerarsi "coatti" nel senso di "futili, inconsistenti", ma che affiorano alla memoria dell'autore quasi per forza e controvoglia.

Comment: Non si tratta di una definizione troppo tecnica per questo contesto letterario del 1947?

Comment: Da questo punto di vista, non saprei esprimere un giudizio; può anche essere che tu abbia ragione, e l'autore intenda che questi spunti siano "obbligatori" per la conoscenza del lettore :)

Comment: Il punto non è la futilità o inconsistenza, ma proprio la coazione, l'obbligo percepito, di svolgere certe azioni (in quel caso, sgombrare il proprio posto a tavola e non toccare niente): si parla soprattutto della “coazione a ripetere”, menzionata anche dal Treccani. Sono quelle che, in modo non tecnico, vengono chiamate manie o fissazioni. Non saprei datarlo in questo uso specifico, ma il pensiero psicoanalitico è arrivato in Italia abbastanza presto; già durante l'epoca fascista c'era una ricca pubblicistica in proposito (soprattutto ostile, ovviamente).

Comment: Per esempio, la coazione a ripetere è già menzionata nell'Enciclopedia Italiana del 1935, nella voce [“Psicoanalisi”](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/psicoanalisi_res-f9e55605-8bb5-11dc-8e9d-0016357eee51_%28Enciclopedia-Italiana%29/).

Comment: @DaG: Definizione dello Zingarelli che ho nel Kindle reader: «**2** (*psicoan.*) Che si riferisce ai pensieri e ai comportamenti che l'individuo si sente costretto a ripetere, anche se irrazionali e inappropriati: *Idee coatte cerchiavano quel cranio della loro corona di ferro* (C.E. GADDA).»

Comment: @DaG: Veramente si addisce al comportamento del vecchio descrito nel brano, ma adesso non capisco bene il significato di "spunti" che io avevo interpretato come spiegazioni senza dare troppi dettagli.

Comment: Io direi che con "spunti coatti" si possa intendere "compulsioni"/"istinti compulsivi".Secondo me per "spunti" l'autore intende alludere al fatto che tali istinti sorgono improvvisamente e non sono controllabili (lo "spunto" è spesso il superamento della resistenza iniziale)